# when to use trigger builds remotely in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have searched many links but could not find the appropriate answer. I need to know when should I use "trigger builds remotely". I have gone through Integration Jenkins with SVN, there I saw that I need to check this option. I am not getting any idea regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

This is used when someone commits to the source control (SVN) it shall ping Jenkins to trigger a build.

Comment: For that I can check poll SCM option to trigger a build.

Answer (score 0):

The "trigger builds remotely" option is used when you want to trigger a build from another tool:

[image]

As explain, you can trigger a job using the Jenkins URL:

```
http://your-jenkins-url/jobs/your-job/build
```

You can secure this URL by using an authentication token.

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have* to use it. There are multiple ways a build can be triggered

- **Build periodically** - based on repeating cron schedule.
- **Poll SCM** - based on SCM commits. This is also required when building on SCM hooks.
- **Build after/before other projects / Various** - multiple ways to setup cross-project dependencies for selecting when to build.
- **Trigger builds remotely** - to delegate the logic for monitoring/triggering builds to 3rd party applications/scripts.

The last one is used when you **don't** want Jenkins to be doing the *triggering* of the jobs (but Jenkins will still do the *execution*). It allows you to trigger a build through a specific URL. To avoid unauthorized triggering (since there is no login at this point), an **authentication token** can be provided.

This URL can be invoked any way you want: manually, command-line script, or some other 3rd-party application.

Comment: could you specify any example on it??

Comment: Of what? Remotely triggering builds? It really depends on your environment and your needs. If you have no need for it that you can think of, then you don't need that.